# Set program menu dir shortcut visible for all users

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have a WiX installer. This installer needs to create a start menu shortcut for all users that want to use the application, and every user that logs the computer must see this shortcut.

This is my code:

```
<Product Id="$(var.GUID_Product)"
     Name="Name"
     Language="!(loc.Language)"
     Version="!(bind.FileVersion.$(var.productFamily)$(var.productSummary))"
     Manufacturer="Manufacturer"
     UpgradeCode="1234-12324" >

<Package 
  Description="Product description"
  Manufacturer="Product manufacturer"
  InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="MainAppInstallFolder" Name="MainApp">

      <!-- Main content directory -->
      <Directory Id="MainContentFolder"  Name="MainContent" />
    </Directory>

    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDemoShortcutDir" Name="$(var.productFamily) $(var.productType)" />
    </Directory>

  </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuDemoShortcutDir">
  <Component Id="CMP_ProgramMenuShortcutDir" Guid="bla">
    <Shortcut Id="DemoShortcutStartMenu"
              Name="MainApp shortcut"
              WorkingDirectory="INSTALLLOCATION"
              Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]MainApp.exe" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDemoShortcutDir" On="uninstall" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="$(var.productKeyPath)" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

This code installs the program menu shortcut correctly. BUT only for the current installation. If I log in to my machine using another credentials, I can't see the shortcut in my windows start menu...

Why is this happening??

NOTE: I'm using WiX 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a per user install, so you need to set InstallScope to be perMachine in the Package element.

Comment: Be sure that the install is elevating, and that the user has admin privileges.